# Why is docker-compose up creating my rails database with a schema preloaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to boot up my rails and postgresql application. I started out with this tutorial here as a base line https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/official-documentation-samples/rails/ but then went off into some modifications of my own to boot up a dev environment.

What I want to accomplish for new developers is the following:

1). `docker-compose up`
2). `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:create`
3). `RAILS_ENV=development rails db:structure:load`

On initial boot up these commands should theoretically give me a scratch rails app. However, what I found is that when I run `docker-compose up`, my database is already created. Here are photos showing this in my postgresql docker container.

[image: Databases]

[image]

So now when I try to run `rails db:structure:load` I run into this error:

[image]

So according to this, the structure.sql is already loaded. My question is why and how to get around this? I've tried:

1). `rails db:drop`
2). `rails db:create`
3). `rails db:structure:load`

I still get the error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.18-alpine3.17
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
      args:
        - GITHUB_CREDENTIALS=${GITHUB_CREDENTIALS}
        - BUNDLE_GEMS_GRAPHQL_PRO=${BUNDLE_GEMS_GRAPHQL_PRO}
    command: ./entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /graph
    volumes:
      - ./:/graph
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      - db
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f /graph/tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm /graph/tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

rails server -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: You have 4.5k points and you post screenshots of text on SO?

Comment: have you tried to remove the `db: volumes` setting? This is all we use for spinning up postgres in docker ```version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.13
    ports:
      - "5450:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pwd123```

Comment: @dbugger your recommendation did avoid database creation but now I received `ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "default_table_access_method"` so now I need to address that. Also don't I need volumes to persist data between shutdown and restart?

Comment: @HansKilian do you have any insight into this?

Comment: default_table_access_method only arrived in postgres 12 -- we don't expect to persist database data between sessions on developer's local boxes -- that's what sample data is for

Comment: Ok so can I conclude that this structure that I am trying to load is actually not from postgresql 11 but probably from postgresql 12 and higher? Is that viable conclusion?